# Как узнать имя текущего модуля в компоненте yii2?

Tags: yii2, компоненты

Как узнать имя текущего модуля в компоненте yii2?

Answer (score 1):

Попробуйте обратиться к `Yii::$app->controller->module->id`

Comment: Неа. Пусто. В контроллерах работает, а вот в компоненте нет.

Comment: Что за компонент вообще? Как альтернативный вариант можно передавать атрибутом в компонент название модуля

Comment: Компонент проверяет гость или нет. Если не гость, то редирект в кабинет. Вообще в нем много функции, это одна из многих. Цепляется он через секцию бутстрап. В итоге задача такая: если не гость и текущий модуль не cabinet, то редиректим юзера на кабинет. Если гость, то ничего не делаем.

Comment: @Максим всё должно работать, если указаны namespace и `use Yii` || `\Yii`